# How can this be a complex if each term isn't an abelian group?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, functors

I'm reading self learning Algebraic Topology from Rotman's Introduction to Algebraic Topology and I've come across this:
[image]

In the book previously a complex is defined as a sequence of abelian groups, but here each $E$ functor is defined as a map to $\text{Comp}$.

How can the $EC$ complex be a complex since each $E_kC$ is an element of Comp and not an abelian group?

Comment: Looks like he says $E_k(C)$ is an abelian group, not a complex (that's $EC$), so I don't see a problem.  Am I reading wrongly?

Comment: Indeed, in Rotman's notation, the complex $EC$ is a sequence of abelian groups $\cdots \to E_{i+1} C \to E_i C \to E_{i-1} C \to \cdots$